# Multiple variable assignment from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, assignment, variable

For example in Python, if we have a list of 3 elements, say `ls = [1,2,3]` and we want to assign a variable to each value (from left to right), one can do as follows: 
`x,y,z = ls` where then, `x` will take the value `1` and so on.

Now if we have a list in Mathematica `ls = {1,2,3}`, is there an analogous way of performing the simultaneous assignment?

Comment: `lst={1,2,3}; {x,y,z}=lst` should just work as is?

Comment: @Nasser Indeed it does, exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Should I remove the post, or would you prefer to add this as an answer and I accept (maybe relevant for future users).